# having iussue serializing the columns for datatables

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am getting my data from sql server adn i am having trouble when i am trying to send back a proper json format

```
{"draw": <cfoutput>#val(draw)#</cfoutput>,
"recordsTotal": <cfoutput>#recordsTotal#</cfoutput>,
"recordsFiltered": <cfoutput>#qFiltered.recordCount#</cfoutput>,
"data": [
<cfif qFiltered.recordcount gt 0>
<cfoutput query="qFiltered" startrow="#val(start+1)#" maxrows="#val(length)#">
    <cfif currentRow gt (start+1)>,</cfif>
        #Replace(SerializeJSON(qFiltered,'struct'),'\','','all')#,
</cfoutput> 
<cfelse>
    ""
</cfif>
]
}
```

someehow the code is ending in invalid nested data, not sure what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Are you getting a server-side error or a datatables (front-end) error? Make sure that the output of `#Replace(SerializeJSON(qFiltered,'struct'),'\','','all')#` is what you want. Not sure why you need to replace backslashes.

Comment: Show us an example of what you believe the resulting DataTables object should look like.

Comment: i am getting right json, but the json is displaying on the screen, datatables not picking it up

Comment: Well, then you have something else wrong with your page.  You need to show us an example of everything you have going on with this.  If you can't provide more info, it's hard to help.

Comment: attaching my cfml code as to what i am doing, i made it appear but it only showing 10 records out of 7000 and no pagination happening 
https://pastebin.com/0TqHePK4

Comment: Whatever else you do to sort this out, don't build JSON by hand. Create a native CFML data structure, *then* serialise it to JSON. Creating JSON by hand is fiddly, makes for convoluted unnecessary code, and is fragile. And just... not how to do it.

Comment: A couple things stand out: 1) in your `DataTable()` call, TYPE and LANGUAGE are both all caps. Javascript is case sensitive, so are you sure about this? Also, in Javascript, `TRUE` (in all caps) is undefined, and therefore a falsey value. `TRUE` is not the same as `true`. And finally, this looks suspicious: `structKeyExists(form,"order[0][column]")` - what the heck is this?! To debug: Open your browser console, view the ajax request coming from `dtAjaxData.cfm?section=users` and then inspect the request, and open it in a new tab. Also, why POST? Make it a GET and change to the URL scope.

Comment: @redtopia, i did as you mentioned and it still shows 10 records, something is wrong with only fetching 10 results

Comment: You should be able to see the ajax request in your browser console that retrieves the next set of results. Look at that request and make sure the payload going to the request is what you expect, and that your code is generating the correct response.

Comment: @cf-uuser Please edit your question to include the code from the pastebin and the additional info from the comments.